# Synchronizing static vector

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

I have few doubts regarding the Vector in the code below being static.
1. by removing the static example

```
public class WaitAndNotify extends Thread   {

private String info;
Vector aVector;
.
.
//same code as below over here
.
.
public static void main (String args []) {
Vector aVector =new Vector();
    new WaitAndNotify("first", aVector).start();
    new WaitAndNotify("second", aVector).start();
    new WaitAndNotify("last", aVector).start();
}
```

the output still remains the same(synchronized). why? if Vector is non-static then each thread,will have its own copy of Vector. So the output should not be syncronized. But it is. why?

2.if the code if as follows:

```
public class WaitAndNotify extends Thread   {

private String info;
static  Vector aVector = new Vector();
 public WaitAndNotify (String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
.
.
//code
.
.
public static void main (String args []) {
    new WaitAndNotify("first").start();
    new WaitAndNotify("second").start();
    new WaitAndNotify("last").start();
}
```

And now here if i Remove static and make vector non-static then the output will not be synchronized. Why so?

Actual code:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class WaitAndNotify extends Thread   {

private String info;
static  Vector aVector = new Vector();

public WaitAndNotify (String info, Vector aVector) {
    this.info = info;
    this.aVector = aVector;
}

public void doTheJob() {
   synchronized ( aVector ) {
    if (  info.equals("last") ) {
        System.out.println(info + " is waking up ...");
        aVector.notifyAll();
        System.out.println(info + " done.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(info + " is waiting");
        try {
            aVector.wait();
        } catch ( IllegalMonitorStateException  e ) {
            System.out.println(info +
              ": IllegalMonitorStateException");
        } catch ( InterruptedException  e ) {
            System.out.println(info +
              ": InterruptedException");
        }
        System.out.println(info + " is awake!");
    }
  }
}


public void run () {
    doTheJob();
}

public static void main (String args []) {
    new WaitAndNotify("first", aVector).start();
    new WaitAndNotify("second", aVector).start();
    new WaitAndNotify("last", aVector).start();
}
}
```

Comment: Mind your formatting - others shall read your code easily; so spend some time to make it easier for them!

Comment: Just a reminder: please take your time and decide if any of the answers did resolve your problem. If so, pick that answer and mark it as "solving your question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both your code samples, there exists only one vector to which all threads have a reference.

To start with the second example: there you have a static variable, so it is share by all `WaitAndNotify` instances.

In the first code example, you create a single vector (using `Vector aVector =new Vector();`) and you pass a reference of it to each thread. Passing a reference does not make a copy of the vector, nor does it create a new vector. If you want to create a new vector for each thread, you have to modify your code as follows:

```
new WaitAndNotify("first", new Vector()).start();
new WaitAndNotify("second", new Vector()).start();
new WaitAndNotify("last", new Vector()).start();
```

Above, three seperate vectors are created (there are three `new Vector()` calls), so each thread has its own vector instance.

Note that if all threads have there own vector (and don't share it to other threads), then you don't need synchronization, which the `Vector` class offers from itself. So you can use a different data structure, such `ArrayList` which does not have synchronization and thus may be a little faster.

Comment: hey hoopje, thank you so much.. I got the concept now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the two situations where "synchronization" works ... there is exactly  **one** vector object in use!

Like: if `aVector` is static, all objects of class WaitAndNotify are seeing the **same** object reference. In the other case, you are providing the **same** vector object to your three instances.

But when you drop static, and each object of WaitAndNotify is creating its own vector, well, then they are all using **different** vector objects.

And guess what happens when three different threads lock on three different locks ... exactly: no synchronization. That is the whole point of **locking** - make sure that these threads have something in common; otherwise the threads exist in their own universe, without any "connection" to other threads.